# Building an arcade machine on iMac 2007 has anybody done it?

Tags: repository, mame

So the goal is to have a dualboot old iMac (El Capitain) and Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS which I will boot as extra workstation and arcade machine (retropie) and start with a question. :)

So my question is has anybody else done this? Is there a RetroPie / RetroArch for Ubuntu precompiled available or does everything needs to be built from scratch? Takes ages to compile on this old machine. Can I contribute with a Ubuntu Repo for a Retroarch / Emulationstation installation if there is not an existing one?

I started from OS X. Installed it, rebooted but ran into problems when installing Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, problems with booting when the EFI of some reson is 32 bit on iMacs from this era. I installed ReFind an EFI boot loader and this solved this problem.

Then I had issues with the Broadcom 4321 wifi to connect to my Unifi AP AC. This awesome answer in the community helped me out. Default driver connected to other wifis but not Unifi of some legacy reason. Other driver fixed this. [Which wifi driver do I choose for MacBook 2007 and how do I install it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/933004/which-wifi-driver-do-i-choose-for-macbook-2007-and-how-do-i-install-it)

Kind Regards Johan

Answer (score 1):

I was successful turning an 24" iMac 2008 into an "arcade machine" the other night by getting both MAME and RetroArch up and running on 20.04.1 LTS.

> Is there a RetroPie / RetroArch for Ubuntu precompiled available

This worked like a charm for me:

```
sudo apt-get install retroarch
```

I specifically used this to install a single core:

```
sudo apt-get install retroarch libretro-snes9x
```

I personally didn't have to add any new repositories (I just double-checked /var/apt) and in the event you have any trouble, these are the official instructions:

https://www.retroarch.com/index.php?page=linux-instructions

I had equal success with:

```
sudo snap install retroarch
```

good luck and have fun!